# An analogue to dotted-pairs for pattern matching in Clojure

Tags: clojure, pattern-matching

Scheme (and CL) has dotted-pairs where both elements of a `cons` cell are specified explicitly (e.g. `(1 . 2)`) rather than implicitly (e.g. `(1 2)` which is read as `(1 . (2 . nil))`).

I came across this [puzzle](http://funcall.blogspot.com/2012/01/small-puzzle.html) where dotted-pairs are used in pattern matching to capture the tail of a list in the object being matched, e.g.:

```
(pmatch '(foo . (? pvar)) '(foo bar baz))
;;      => ((pvar bar baz))
```

Here `'(foo . (? pvar))` is a pattern and `'(foo bar baz)` is the object matched against the pattern. `foo` in the pattern is a literal, whereas `(? pvar)` is a pattern variable which matches `(bar baz)` and binds the symbol `pvar` to that match. The `pmatch` function returns an association list of pattern variables and bound matches.

Had the pattern been `'(foo (? pvar))`, the match would fail, because `baz` would not match anything in the pattern.

I've implemented the puzzle in Clojure, and I pass all of JRM's test cases apart from the dotted-pair one. I'm trying to figure out how to possibly support the dotted-pair pattern as well.

Here's my current solution:

```
(defn pattern-variable? [pv]
  (when (seq? pv)
    (let [[qmark var] pv]
     (and (= (count pv) 2)
          (= qmark '?)
          (or (symbol? var)
              (keyword? var)))))

(defn pattern-variable [pv]
  (second pv))

(defn pmatch
  ([pat obj] (pmatch pat obj {}))
  ([pat obj binds]
     (cond (not (coll? pat))
           (when (= pat obj) binds)
           (pattern-variable? pat)
           (assoc binds (pattern-variable pat) obj)
           (seq? pat) (let [[pat-f & pat-r] pat]
                      (when (seq? obj)
                        (when-let [binds (pmatch pat-f (first obj) binds)]
                          (pmatch pat-r (next obj) binds))))
           :else nil)))
```

So how can I support patterns that match the rest of the object in Clojure without dotted-pairs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*(Edit: Added a slightly longer, but significantly clearer matcher impl + a demo. The original remains below the horizontal rule.)*

One solution would be to introduce a different notation to signify a variable to be matched against the tail of a seq, or "variable after dot". Another one would be to reserve `&` as a special symbol in patterns with the requirement that it may only be followed by a single pattern variable to be matched against the rest of the expression / object, which must be a seq. I'll explore the first approach below.

Here I took the liberty of changing the notation so that `~foo` is a regular occurrence of the variable `foo` and `~@foo` is a tail occurrence. (One could permit `~@`-matching against subsequences, perhaps matching the minimal initial fragment of a sequence, if any, such that the remainder can be matched against the rest of the pattern; I'll just say this is out of scope for this answer, though. ;-))

Note that these really are different occurrences of the same variable -- i.e. there is still only one variable type -- since no distinction is being made between bindings arising from `~`-occurrences and bindings arising from `~@`-occurrences.

Also note that the examples in the post you linked to do not test for attempts to rebind a previously bound variable (e.g. try `(pmatch '(~x ~x) '(foo bar))`, `(pmatch '((? x) (? x)) '(foo bar))` in the original syntax). The code below returns `nil` in such cases, as it does when the match fails for other reasons.

First, a demo:

```
user> (pmatch '(foo ~pvar1 ~pvar2 bar) '(foo 33 (xyzzy false) bar))
{pvar2 (xyzzy false), pvar1 33}
user> (pmatch '(~av ~@sv) '(foo bar baz))
{sv (bar baz), av foo}
user> (pmatch '(foo ~pvar1 ~pvar2 bar) '(foo 33 false bar))
{pvar2 false, pvar1 33}
user> (pmatch '(foo ~pvar bar) '(quux 33 bar))
nil
user> (pmatch '(a ~var1 (nested (c ~var2))) '(a b (nested (c d))))
{var2 d, var1 b}
user> (pmatch '(a b c) '(a b c))
{}
user> (pmatch '(foo ~pvar1 ~pvar2 bar) '(foo 33 (xyzzy false) bar))
{pvar2 (xyzzy false), pvar1 33}
user> (pmatch '(foo ~@pvar) '(foo bar baz))
{pvar (bar baz)}
user> (pmatch '(~? quux) '(foo quux))
{? foo}
user> (pmatch '~? '(foo quux))
{? (foo quux)}
user> (pmatch '(? ? ?) '(foo quux))
nil
```

Here's the matcher:

```
(defn var-type [pat]
  (when (seq? pat)
    (condp = (first pat)
      'clojure.core/unquote :atomic
      'clojure.core/unquote-splicing :sequential
      nil)))

(defn var-name [v]
  (when (var-type v)
    (second v)))

(defmulti pmatch*
  (fn [pat expr bs]
    (cond
      (= :atomic (var-type pat))        :atom
      (= :sequential (var-type pat))    nil
      (and (seq? pat) (seq? expr))      :walk
      (not (or (seq? pat) (seq? expr))) :exact
      :else                             nil)))

(defmethod pmatch* :exact [pat expr bs]
  (when (= pat expr) bs))

(defmethod pmatch* :atom [v expr bs]
  (if-let [[_ x] (find bs (var-name v))]
    (when (= x expr) bs)
    (assoc bs (var-name v) expr)))

(defmethod pmatch* :walk [pat expr bs]
  (if-let [[p] pat]
    (if (= :sequential (var-type p))
      (when (and (seq? expr) (not (next pat)))
        (if-let [[_ xs] (find bs (var-name p))]
          (when (= xs expr) bs)
          (assoc bs (var-name p) expr)))
      (when-let [[x] expr]
        (when-let [m (pmatch* p x bs)]
          (pmatch* (next pat) (next expr) m))))))

(defmethod pmatch* nil [& _] nil)

(defn pmatch
  ([pat expr] (pmatch pat expr {}))
  ([pat expr bs] (pmatch* pat expr bs)))
```

---

And here's the original monolithic version:

```
(defn pmatch
  ([pat expr] (pmatch pat expr {}))
  ([pat expr bs]
     (letfn [(atom-var? [pat]
               (and (seq? pat) (= 'clojure.core/unquote (first pat))))
             (seq-var? [pat]
               (and (seq? pat) (= 'clojure.core/unquote-splicing
                                  (first pat))))
             (v [var] (second var))
             (matcha [a e bs]
               (if-let [[_ x] (find bs (v a))]
                 (and (or (= x e) nil) bs)
                 (assoc bs (v a) e)))
             (matchs [s e bs]
               (when (seq? e)
                 (if-let [[_ xs] (find bs (v s))]
                   (or (= xs e) nil)
                   (assoc bs (v s) e))))]
       (when bs
         (cond
           (atom-var? pat)
           (matcha pat expr bs)

           (seq-var? pat)
           (matchs pat expr bs)

           (and (seq? pat) (seq? expr))
           (if-let [[p] pat]
             (if (seq-var? p)
               (matchs p expr bs)
               (when-let [[x] expr]
                 (when-let [m (pmatch p x bs)]
                   (recur (next pat) (next expr) m))))
             (when-not (first expr)
               bs))

           (not (or (seq? pat) (seq? expr)))
           (when (= pat expr)
             bs)

           :else nil)))))
```

Comment: Nice job! Multimethods definitely make the code clearer. I think there's a bug in `pmatch*` `:walk` where you're looking for previous bindings of the same pattern variable: `(if-let [[_ xs] (find bs (var-name bs))]` which should be `(if-let [[_ xs] (find bs (var-name p))]`.

Comment: Also, while writing the question, I thought about using `.` or `&` as a separator where the pattern variable after the separator would match the tail of the object. But I definitely like your use of `~` and `~@` much more. Another thing that I worried about was that I would have to check the pattern for syntax errors, i.e. `(foo . (? var) bar)` should be illegal, and I think this remains a problem in your solution as well, whereas in Scheme the reader would take care of that.

Comment: Ah, good catch on `:walk`, fixed. Also, agreed about `(foo . (? var) bar)` style patterns; I've added an extra check in `:walk` to make matches against such patterns always fail.